# Sistema de Login con Sesiones en Ajax Jquery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un dilema:
Mi idea es que lo primero que salga siempre es el login pero sin hacerlo index.html y sea login.html, entonces hago la comprobación de si hay un usuario iniciado y sino hay ninguno te lleve al login, la comprobación la hace bien porque si no hay un usuario iniciado me lleva al login pero en esa redirección se ve durante unos milisegundos la pagina de index.html y va al login.html.
Igual me he complicado y tendría que poner el login como index.
**Main.js**

```js
 function comprobarSesion() {
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "php/index.php",

      success: function (resultado) {

        console.log(resultado);      
        if (resultado){
          if (resultado != 1 || resultado != 2) {

            $('.user').text('Bienvenido ' + resultado);
  
            $('<a class="nav-link d-block cerrar-sesion" href="#" >' + resultado + ',<b>Logout</b></a>').appendTo(".cerrar");
          }
        } else {
        window.location.replace("login.html");
        }       
      },
      error: function (xhr) {
        alert("Atencion: se ha producido un error");
        $("#mensaje1").append(xhr.statusText + xhr.responseText);
      },
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Index.php**

```js
<?php
include("conexion.php");
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

    if($_SESSION['user']['id_rol']== 1){
        echo "Admin ";
       echo $_SESSION['user']['id_rol'];

    } else if($_SESSION['user']['id_rol']== 2){
        echo "Gestor ";
       echo $_SESSION['user']['id_rol'];


    } else{
        echo "Empleado ";
      
        echo $_SESSION['user']; // es el resultado en AJAX

    } 

   
   
}
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, cual es el error/problema especificamente. lee [ask]

Comment: Te dejo la url y un usuario para que pruebes y veas lo que pasa. https://adrigp.com.es/PFCAdrian/       use:marta pass:123 date cuenta lo que hace cuando no hay sesion y te lleva al login